# Just installed OSSEC, what next?

Tags: ossec

We need file integrity monitoring on our windows servers (a webserver and a database server) and before we drop money on Tripwire, I'm checking out OSSEC. I installed a local installation to test with on my ubuntu laptop, and it appears to be working. I received some email alerts about it being the first time I've logged in with that account, used sudo, etc.

My question now: what are some common tasks I should try next? I would like to go in and change some file that OSSEC is monitoring to see if it alerts on that, but I don't know what the default rules are monitoring.

Answer (score 2):

> My question now: what are some common tasks I should try next?

OSSEC has default rules to perform log analysis, file integrity checking, rootkit detection, ...

You can try some common tasks such as:

- monitoring kernel log by adding the below config to `ossec.conf`:

> ```
> <localfile>
>     <log_format>syslog</log_format>
>     <location>/var/log/kern.log</location>
> </localfile>
> ```

- Adding some exclude words which you don't want to getting alert to `/var/ossec/rules/local_rules.xml`:

```
RRD_update|getaddrinfo|does not represent a number in line|error.class.php|Bind to port|errorsign.jpg|error.gif|error retrieving information about user
```

and overwrite some rules:

```
  <rule id="5703" level="10" frequency="4" timeframe="360" overwrite="yes">
    <if_matched_sid>5702</if_matched_sid>
    <options>no_email_alert</options>
    <description>Possible breakin attempt </description>
    <description>(high number of reverse lookup errors).</description>
  </rule>
```

- write several shell scripts for active response
- [integrate](http://www.ossec.net/main/splunk-ossec-integration) OSSEC
  with Splunk

> I would like to go in and change some file that OSSEC is monitoring to
>   see if it alerts on that, but I don't know what the default rules are
>   monitoring.

You can search the keyword `integrity` in `rules` folder:

```
# grep -lir "integrity" /var/ossec/rules/
/var/ossec/rules/msauth_rules.xml
/var/ossec/rules/syslog_rules.xml
/var/ossec/rules/ossec_rules.xml
```

It's rule ID 550:

```
  <rule id="550" level="7">
    <category>ossec</category>
    <decoded_as>syscheck_integrity_changed</decoded_as>
    <description>Integrity checksum changed.</description>
    <group>syscheck,</group>
  </rule>
```

Comment: Exemplary answer, this site needs more of these.